# Popular application Unetbootin executible file does nothing

Tags: 13.10, executable

Grabbed unetbootin-linux-585 because I want to make an installation flash drive for Ubuntu 12.04 (13.10 is unusable with bugs). I don't normally work with downloaded executables in linux, but I followed the instructs on the website. I changed the file property to 'executable' and ran chmod +x on the file location. When I try to run the file graphically or via the terminal, nothing happens. This can't be a problem with the software; it's too widely known and used. It should do something when executed. I'm working in a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.10. What can I do?

Edit: the exact command, as requested: chmod +x ./Downloads/unetbootin-linux

Everything else was done graphically. The file is checked to run as an executable and the permissions are Read and Write for Owner and Group. Nothing happens.

I can open a terminal and type ./Downloads/unetbootin-linux-585 which returns a fresh prompt, no hanging. I rebooted my computer and downloaded a fresh copy of the file and repeated these steps. Still nothing.

I could just use the windows version to complete this task, but I'm concerned that if something as simple as running an executable, without adding repositories or using a package manager, isn't going to work, then it indicates something more broadly wrong with my configuration. This is my second fresh install of 13.10 in as many days. Things haven't been functioning smoothly.

Comment: Either install from the repository as Avinash suggested or [edit] your post and include the _exact_ commands you ran. Always include the _exact_ commands you ran, issues like this are usually because of minor mistakes or syntax errors but we can't help unless we know what you ran.

Comment: @DualBooty This sort of thing *can* be a bug in the program itself... but it might not be, so let's see. You say "nothing happens." What do you mean? When you run it from a terminal, does it end immediately (giving you another usable prompt)? Or does it hang, leaving you with a cursor at the beginning of a blank line in the terminal (a line that does *not* accept shell commands)? Or does something else happen? Also like terdon says, please show us exactly what you've typed (as well as any output) starting from the first command you ran. You can edit your question to add all this information.

Comment: Try this command, `sudo bash ~/Downloads/unetbootin-linux-585`

Comment: Result is: `cannot execute binary file`

Comment: This problem originally occurred with Ubuntu 13.10. I've since used the Windows version of Unetbootin to create a fresh install of Xubuntu 12.04. Trying to execute the Unetbootin Linux binary gives the same results as before, i.e. nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install unetbootin from the repository(Universe).Run the below command on terminal to install unetbootin,

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Run the below command to enable universe repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

And don't forget to update the repositories before installing unetbootin.

```
sudo apt-get update
```